# re-install paid subscription on new Android device

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription

I have an inapp subscription.  I am trying to insure the re-installation of the app on the same or a new will recognize that the user has a valid subscription.  The "already owned" response is supposed to have a value of "7", which works fine for consumable, managed products.  For subscriptions, however, I do not get a "7" response.  The messages are different, too.  For a managed, consumable product the message is "Item already owned" with a "7" response.  For subscriptions the message is "You already own this item", with NO "7" response, and the IAB result is "-1005:User cancelled".  The subscription is active in Google Wallet, has not been cancelled.  I get the response, I believe, from the alert box dismissal.

The question is, how do I recognize this response to the IABsetup?  I have tried if request.mResponse = 1, but that does not work.  I aparently do not get a useful response code for subscriptions.  During testing, I have to turn off debug to upload the .apk so this is even more difficult to follow.

Why would the subscription response from the server differ from the managed product response for already owned items?

I need to be able to activate the app based on the already owned response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the IabHelper.java has this:

```
else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        logDebug("Purchase canceled - Response: " + getResponseDesc(responseCode));        
        result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_USER_CANCELED, "User canceled.");
        if (mPurchaseListener != null) mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
    }
```

I changed to this:

```
else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        logDebug("Purchase canceled - Response: " + getResponseDesc(responseCode));        
        result = new IabResult(responseCode, "User canceled.");
        if (mPurchaseListener != null) mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
    }
```

Note the change from (IABHELPER_USER_CANCELED, "User canceled.") to (responseCode, "User Canceled")

Now the responseCode is passing to the

```
public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase info)
```

so I can determine if the response is a dialog cancel and allow the active subscription to re-install and contact my server.  At that point I am doing the 0Auth API call to Google to verify the installation and active subscription.

There may be alternate ways to do this, but this worked.

Hope this helps the 3 people in the world who are doing Android inapp subscriptions.

Comment: Theres at least 4 because I'm doing it as well know. Something I've found useful and sorry if its obvious to others, but once the IabSetup has been completed I call `getPurchases` to see if there are any existing purchases for the items in question. That way if you get a 7 back you can attempt to restore the data to your server. Should help with people with multiple devices

Comment: I agree, but I still do not get a 7 back for a paid subscription.  At least, not that I could detect.  The process is SUPPOSED to tell you "You already own this item" and send the IABSetup a 7.  It doesn't send the 7, just the 1 for a canceled dialogue.  Of course, I could have missed something...

Comment: We published our subscription model on 12/12/13.  We only get a purchase token 50% of the time from Google Play.  We have tried unsuccessfully since then to find out why from Google.  So, after 30 days we cancel the service, even though they have paid through a subscription.  I was wondering if there was some sample code to request the PurchaseToken immediately after the sale if we don't get it?